# iPhone zoom map to show all pins

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

I've just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576676/android-map-zoom-to-show-all-pins) for doing this on the Android but has anyone got this to work on the iPhone?

What I'm looking for is a method that will zoom the map to show all pins that are showing...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution! :)

http://sdhillon.com/find-the-center-and-span-of-a-set-of-points-android-and-iphone-example/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there's a built in method, but the usual way is to loop through your annotations, looking at their coordinates, and find the maximum and minimum latitudes and longitudes. You'll end up with 4 numbers, you can create a region from them and set the map to that region.

Comment: Does anyone know how to zoom to this region? I know how to zoom to a location on the map but setting the zoom level is where I'm struggling!

Comment: The maps in iOS don't really have zoom regions. Instead, you set the region and the OS sets it to the optimum zoom level. Use `setRegion:animated` to set the region.